# Gradle Project Sync Failed - Unresolved dependencies

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've taken an Android project that was created in IntelliJ and imported it into AndroidStudio.  After looking at Googles hopeless instructions for how to migrate a project to Gradle I pressed buttons at random and prayed to the gods of droid whilst sacrificing a small innocent child and somehow eventually ended up with a Gradle controlled project that synced, built and ran on my Android devices.

I then added some additional dependencies to my build.gradle file:

```
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.12'
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-spring-android:1.4.12'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:1.18.0-rc'
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-google-http-client:1.4.12'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
```

Now when I try to sync Gradle I get the following message:
Gradle Project sync Failed.  Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.

In the Gradle Sync window I get the following messages:
Unresolved Dependencies:

> Error:com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.18.0-rc
>   Error:com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-spring-android:1.4.12

...
and so on for each of the dependencies that I have listed.
How might I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

OK I've figured it out.
I added

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

to the bottom of my build.gradle file.

It was obviously struggling to find a repository to load from.

The script already had

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

This it would seem was insufficient.